# Value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have written ASP.NET MVC Code for CRUD but while Updating,Deleting and Details the page is throwing the error as value can not be null.my code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id=0) 
            {  
                var alb=db.Albums.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.AlbumId==id);
                return View(alb);
            }
public ActionResult Detail(int id=0) 
        {
            var alb=db.Albums.Find(id);
            return View(alb);   
        }
public ActionResult Delete(int id=0) 
        {
            var album = db.Albums.Find(id);
            return View(album);

        }
```

and my Model is

```
public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }
        public String Price { get; set; }
        public String AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
```

This is because the variable alb and album is showing me the null value its not getting any ID.
so suggest me on this.

Comment: Which programming language would this be?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: yehhhh...it is ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Fix the logic of your program so that you don't pass a null view to the page. In some situations you may need to avoid the view altogether.

Comment: yes....for that i have passed the id to the page and kept it as hidden @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.AlbumId)

Comment: Do you have any data in the database?

Comment: yes i do have 6 data in my database

Comment: can any one have an idea?

Comment: And you get the id parameter with a value, or is it missing (and then it get assigned the default value of '0'). I wonder if you pass the value, when you have a default mvc application you probably have a link this: /album/detail/5 ?

Comment: i guess this is because of the model that i have created m editing my question

Comment: it will not only update,delete the AlbumId but also the data associated with it in Genre and Artist as well.so i have to keep the GenreId and ArtistId as hidden as well

Comment: My question was: do you get a value for the id other than zero, when you enter the `detail` method?

Comment: no..if i place the debugger and see then i get the value of "alb" as null in var alb=db.Albums.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.AlbumId==id);

Answer (score 1):

> This is because the variable alb and album is showing me the null
>   value its not getting any ID

If there is no record in your database then you should handle it gracefully in code. You should have something like:

```
var alb=db.Albums.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.AlbumId==id);
if (alb==null) {
    // TempData, simplest way to give you an example
    TempData["error_msg"] = "the record does not exists";   
    return RedirectToAction("index", "error");
}
return View(alb);
```

in your ErrorController

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ViewBag.ErrorMsg = TempData["error_msg"];
    return View();
}
```

in the view (`Index.cshtml`) for your error controller

```
<h1>You have been, or trying to be, a naughty boy</h1>
<p>@ViewBag.ErrorMsg</p>
```

This is **not** the most elegant solution though but good enough to get you started. I think the most important part of my answer is not the code I gave you but the suggestion to **handle that kind of situation (null values / missing or invalid records) in code**.

Comment: yes..fine this is the way when we get the error but why i am getting an error if i do have lots of records in my database. That's what my question was...